# OpenVPN --show-pkcs11-slots not available on Windows version?

Tags: windows, openvpn

I am currently having issues with OpenVPN, it appears that the "--show-pkcs11-slots" switch does not work on OpenVPN for Windows, I have also tried the --help switch and it does not appear to be documented.

I am using:

OpenVPN 2.2.0 Win32-MSVC++ [SSL] [LZO2] built on Apr 26 2011

The error message is as follows:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN2\bin>openvpn --show-pkcs11-slots
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Smart Card Bundle\opensc-pkcs11.dll" 1
>   Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in
>   [CMD-LINE]:1: show -pkcs11-slots (2.2.1) Use --help for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem - OpenVPN 2.2 does not come pre-compiled with PKCS11 support (at least not on Windows) so you can find a build of OpenVPN that has support for PKCS11 (along with OpenSC) here: opensc-project.org/downloads/users/alonbl/build